# Are SSH commands run on the target’s machines’s CPU or on the client’s CPU?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

So I have this Raspberry Pi that login to using SSH when I want to use it.

I want to know if the Raspberry Pi’s CPU is running the SSH commands or it is just sending data to my laptop so that it can run on my laptop’s CPU?

Comment: ok distinction requried. ssh runs on local system (client) and the remote system (server) and has extensions that enable connectivity of varying types from client to server (like SFTP/SCP). The Shell that SSH projects to the user however executes commands on the server. use of features like SFTP rely on operations on both the client and the server. SSH/RSH are Shells, so they take input and provide output. from the client perspective the output is remote, and from the servers perspective the client is providing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SSH commands are always run on the remote machine you are logging into.

This is always the case. Not just in the case of a Raspberry Pi. You login to the remote machine via some kind of terminal client, and when you are logged in you are running commands as if your keyboard, mouse and screen are directly connected to that remote machine.

As the [Wikipedia entry for SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_(Secure_Shell)) explains:

> “SSH or Secure Shell is a cryptographic network protocol for operating network services securely over an unsecured network. Typical applications include remote command-line, login, and remote command execution, but any network service can be secured with SSH.”

The key word is always “remote”; SSH is for dealing with remote access via the command line.